# How to empty a table without having DROP/TRUNCATE command privilege?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am getting this error.

[image]

My client said there is no option to give me those privileges. It's a very restricted cPanel or something.

So I need to find a way to empty the table, and also reset the incremental values, etc without having DROP command privilege. Any suggestions?

Comment: `delete * from table_name` ? Isn't the best way and will not reset any autoincrement values.

Comment: *"My client said there is no option to give me those privileges. It's a very restricted cPanel or something."* Sounds like the Client does not want to give it.. cPanel by the way has nothing to do with MySQL privileges, you can use it yes to make MySQL user accounts and control the privileges

Comment: @RaymondNijland Maybe he doesn't want to give it or he doesn't know how to. Either way I am stuck with the limited privileges and have to make it work somehow

Comment: *"Maybe he doesn't want to give it or he doesn't know how to"* Then you need to convince the client why you need this and or let the client email somebody to do it for him/her when shared webhosting is involved *"Either way I am stuck with the limited privileges and have to make it work somehow "* Not possible unless you have `DELETE` and `ALTER` privileges like other answers/comments suggested. working.

Comment: .. *"My client said there is no option to give me those privileges"* Well tell your client then you can't finish the project but the client still needs to pay the bill for the time spent for extra motivation into getting the minimal privileges for getting it working..

Answer (score 5):

I am not here to talk security .. But if you simply wanted to "clear" the table.. You can use `DELETE` with a `CONDITIONAL` .. IE

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id > 0;
```

The trouble with this is if you had `ID`s 1 - 300 in the database .. Without `TRUNCATING` the `ID`s will start from 301 and on --

Comment: Any ways to reset the ID so it starts from 1 again?

Comment: @TrondroMulligan `ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`

Comment: What about going to Operations > Table Options and changing the AUTO_INCREMENT value? http://prntscr.com/mwz8a1

Comment: I assumed you don't have `ALTER` capabilities since you can't `TRUNCATE` but yes, you can reset the `auto_increment` if you have `ALTER` privileges.

Comment: Be careful when resetting the `AUTO_INCREMENT` as if there's any other data that refers to previous records it will now get linked in to these new, probably unrelated records.

Answer (score 2):

Without dropping and recreating the table, there is no way to reset the auto increment to start over again at 1, or at any value you've already used.

If you have DELETE privileges, you could empty the table by doing a DELETE FROM, but the auto increment won't reset as long as the table exists.

Comment: I don't have the privileges to delete tables either or create new tables.